# How can I validate a nested POST body payload with the checkSchema middleware in express-validator?

Tags: express, express-validator

Given the following sample POST body:

```
User = {
    email: string; //required, email
    password: string; //required, min length 8

    profile: {
        firstName: string;  //required
        lastName: string;   //required
        gender: Gender;     //required, enum (M/F)
    }
}
```

How can I define an express `ValidationSchema` to validate the nested `Profile` object and its props inside the `User`

```
userValidatorSchema: ValidationSchema = {
    email: {
        isEmail: {}
    },
    password: {
        exists: {
            options: {checkNull: true},
            errorMessage: 'Null value'
        },
        isEmpty: {
            negated: true,
            errorMessage: 'Empty string'
        }        
    }
    //Profile validation??
```

[Express-validator docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html) make it look like this is not possible with express-validator. If so, what is a more versatile validator for express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this approach:

```
// Profile validation
profile: {
  optional: false
},
'profile.firstName': {
  notEmpty: true,
  optional: false
}
// ...others
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, could you check on my question please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292782/express-server-doesnt-start-after-adding-checkschema-from-express-validator